# controller action name of module is displaying in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, controllers, action

I am trying to find **controller action** of module for below Observer code, so that i can see those action names in log file : **called_action_names.log** ,  its displaying those names in log files.

**issue** :  along with this its displaying those names in **site** & now its not saving the uploaded image in site once we click on "**save design**" button.

you can see text `catalog_product_view` in top of the page

```
public function onControllerActionPredispatch($observer)
    {
      Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName(), Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'called_action_names.log');
        if (
            $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'example_amasty_createProduct' &&
            !Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
        ) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAmastyExampleCustomProductInfo(
                $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()
                    ->getRequest()->getPost('Amasty')
            );
        }
        else if (
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() &&
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getAmastyExampleCustomProductInfo()
        ) {

        }

     echo $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();
    }

   }
```

**config.xml**

```
<controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <Amasty_Example>
                    <class>example/observer</class>
                    <method>onControllerActionPredispatch</method>
                </Amasty_Example>
            </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch>
```

when i replace line : `<class>example/observer</class>` by `<class>my_module/observer</class>` , it dont show any issue. but real module name is **"example"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `echo` from your observer code.

```
public function onControllerActionPredispatch($observer)
{
  Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName(), Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'called_action_names.log');
    if (
        $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'example_amasty_createProduct' &&
        !Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
    ) {
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAmastyExampleCustomProductInfo(
            $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()
                ->getRequest()->getPost('Amasty')
        );
    }
    else if (
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() &&
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getAmastyExampleCustomProductInfo()
    ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Its really strange that we can display in frontend with help of observer code, i thought we can do it by only template files..... Thanks a lot.....